# ActiveAdmin on Heroku, error on show action only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activeadmin

I have deployed AvtiveAdmin to Heroku, I am able to access the dashboard, create/update actions as well as save records to the database successfully however when I attempt to view the show action for a record an application error is thrown.

I am using rails version 3.2, I have no issues with my development environment and no errors are reported when deploying to Heoku. Below are the application logs from the failing request

```
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.15/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/f

2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__808874074589373381__call__3072339077006452195__callbacks'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:132:in `forward'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:241:in `fetch'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:50:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:181:in `lookup'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:65:in `call!'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-03T04:24:00+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /admin/categories/1] miss
```

EDIT: I added the thin gem as suggested in the comment below, redeployed and pulled more log lines which shows the following error

```
2012-03-03T04:58:54+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-03T04:58:54+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/admin/categories/1" for 76.120.46.114 at 2012-03-03 04:58:54 +0000
2012-03-03T04:58:54+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-03T04:58:54+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
2012-03-03T04:58:54+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...tegory' AND "active_admin_comments"."resource_id" = 1 AND "a...
2012-03-03T04:58:54+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2012-03-03T04:58:54+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "active_admin_comments"  WHERE "active_admin_comments"."resource_type" = 'Category' AND "active_admin_comments"."resource_id" = 1 AND "active_admin_comments"."namespace" = 'admin'):
2012-03-03T04:58:54+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: render renderer_for(:show)
2012-03-03T04:58:54+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: Can you show the entire stacktrace, including the error? Also, why are you using webrick on heroku? Make sure the 'thin' gem is being installed in production.

Comment: I added the thin gem as suggested, I am a newbie at RoR and Heroku so thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this issue has been resolve upstream: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1094

So just put `gem 'active_admin', :git => 'https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'` into your Gemfile and `bundle install`.

*My personal advice, however, would be to stay away from active admin for now, and stick to doing it the rails way, just because there's enough to learn with rails alone without needing to learn yet another framework.*